# How to use ConversationHandler for Telegram bot in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm currently writing a Telegram bot using python-telegram-bot as a wrapper. I want to try and host this on AWS Lambda. However, so far the examples I've seen are simple, dumb bots that are unable to continue a conversation. I'm leveraging ConversationHandler to run the bot's conversations but this doesn't work well on AWS Lambda. I'm not sure how to fix this issue.

```
bot = MyBot()

def lambda_handler(event=None, context=None):
    try:
        dispatcher = bot.updater.dispatcher
        message = json.loads(event['body'])
        print("Incoming:", message)
        dispatcher.process_update(Update.de_json(message, bot.updater.bot))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return {"statusCode": 500}
    bot.updater.idle()

    return {"statusCode": 200}
```

How can I get the bot to hold a conversation state throughout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConversationHandler` stores the state internally, i.e. in memory. I don't know how AWS handles initialization of variables, but if the `ConversationHandler` is initialized anew on each incoming update, it won't remember which state each conversation was in. If you can use some sort of database/file storage on AWS, you can try to use PTBs [persistence](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Making-your-bot-persistent) setup to store the converstanion states and reload them for each incoming update.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`

Comment: From my understanding, AWS lambda refires the same function i.e. lambda_handler() whenever the webhook is triggered. But I'm not sure if there's a way to reference a pre-existing lambda instance. My current idea is to probably use webhook to start the function and use polling to keep it alive before switching back to webhook when the lambda instance is about to close

Comment: Mixing webhook & polling sounds like a bad idea. I suggest to rather investigate if it's possible to keep some data in memory between function calls.

Comment: AWS Lambda isn't able to maintain memory across different function calls as the next function call might not be assigned to the same server. My final solution was to switch to either Heroku or EC2 instead.

Comment: Mh, okay. If my answer was helpful for you, please consider accepting it :)